# Can the robot be detected via HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: php

I would like to protect my site from other websites that steal my content. Can I detect such an impostor by checking the HTTP_REFERER variable?

Example:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){ //ex: otherdomain.com  
        die('Access blocked');
    }else{
        // ok
    }
?>
```

Comment: not unless you never want anyone who found your site on google to access it by clicking on the link in the google search results. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: If  allowed the google domain? Could I use this then?

Comment: yeah and every other search engine, and any other site which might (or whose users might) decide to create a link to yours because they like it (think social media etc). The list of allowed sites would be very difficult to keep up to date, and you don't want to lose genuine traffic. Plus, have you got evidence that robots are coming to your site with the referrer field set? Who says they haven't spoofed it to be something you regard as legitimate, anyway? preventing this kind of unwanted access is a broad topic not easily answered by a quick SO question, I suggest you study it in depth

Comment: I have domena1.com and domain2.com websites with software (programs for computers) in the trail, demo, etc. versions. I can download them from my server or the author. I would like to allow only downloading files from domain2.com only for domain1.com. I would like to use HTTP_REFERER in the download.php file.(my pages are legal, I have the author's consent);)

Comment: Well that's a somewhat different question. You could do it, but be aware that the referrer field can be spoofed easily, as I mentioned already. An authentication scheme might be more secure. The full requirements and situation are not clear but that may be a possible alternative. Your description is not detailed enough to be certain

Comment: In that case, thank you for help :).

Comment: Scraping and hotlinking are entirely different subjects. Whoever writes a program to steal you site will never take care of composing an HTTP_REFERER header and then populate it with a different domain—what for?

Comment: This is true; to clarify my earlier comments it should be noted there's no requirement to supply any kind of referrer value in the request at all. Legitimate requests made directly (i.e. without clicking on a link from another site) will not contain one, and the various spoofing methods could also include removal of the information entirely if desired.

Comment: So it is not worth using this method?. Please explain